# JNDI/Tomcat no appropriate service handler found even the application still working

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat, ejb, jndi

I have a Spring application running on vFabric tc server which extended from Tomcat 7. Current application has about three data sources need to change to JNDI. I have put the connection pool in to `Server/context.xml` and call JNDI service in `web.xml` and `applicationContext.xml`.

The problem comes when start the application, there are exceptions thrown when Spring initializing framework servlet as this:

```
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'MyAppName'
Feb 3, 2013 7:34:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\STS_3.1\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.2.RELEASE\baseInstance\webapps\manager
Feb 3, 2013 7:35:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\STS_3.1\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.2.RELEASE\baseInstance\webapps\ROOT
Feb 3, 2013 7:35:09 PM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:412)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:699)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:631)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:485)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:539)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:237)
at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1061)
at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:671)
at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:270)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1100)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1618)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:385)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1042)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:301)
... 38 more
Feb 3, 2013 7:35:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
```

I have to highlight that there are three JNDI data sources but the `no appropriate service handler found` exceptions repeatingly thrown about `5 times`.

But after that the application still runs fine without any issue.

So how come with these exceptions and how to overcome them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the problem:

When setting JNDI connection pool in Tomcat( element in Context.xml), I gave too many connections allowed for the pool

```
<Resource name="jdbc/schema_A" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:orcl"
    username="app_A" password="app_A" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" />
```

above setting(maxActive/maxIdle) is maybe too much for local oracle service workload(production server is fine) hence the exception and the application still running. So I change it to

```
<Resource name="jdbc/schema_A" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:orcl"
    username="app_A" password="app_A" maxActive="1" maxIdle="1" maxWait="-1" />
```

Now everything is working without issues...cheers..